# flutter isar @enumerated not working on isar 3.0.0

Tags: flutter

I see that folks are having issues with isar @enumerated on isar 3.0.1, but I'm facing this issue on isar 3.0.0 too. When I run **flutter pub run build_runner build** I get

```
type 'EnumElementImpl' is not a subtype of type 'ClassElement' in type cast
```

I'm using flutter 3.3.2. How do I fix this issue? Any help greatly appreciated!

```
@collection
class Word {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  late int rootWordId;

  late String engWord;
  late String altWord;
  late String iast;

  //@Enumerated(EnumType.ordinal)
  @enumerated
  late WordType wordType;

  late String? engExample;
  late String? altExample;
  late String? audioFile;
  late String? image;
}

enum WordType {
  masculine,
  feminine,
  neuter,
  verb,
  adjective,
  noun,
  ind,
  adverb,
  antonym,
  indecl,
  expr,
  conj,
  pronoun,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the problems with Isar's repository it looks like this is a problem `Isar version below 3.0.5`.

I also used Isar database in my project with version `3.0.5` and I just used an enum and hit the `flutter pub run build_runner build` and it works as expected. So using the [latest version of Isar](https://pub.dev/packages/isar) may solve your problem.

Here is my database snapshot.

[image]